# Sublime Text 3 snippet doesn't show up in "Goto anywhere" dialog

Tags: sublimetext3

I've wrote my first Sublime Text 3 snipped, registering it with `prn` trigger and limiting it to PHP only:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
echo '<pre>'.print_r(${1:\$variable}, TRUE).'</pre>';
die();
    ]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>prn</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

When I open any `.php` file and type `prn`, eveything is fine -- my snippet appears as first and I can press `Tab` or `Enter` to place it in the editor, at cursor position:

[image]

However, no matter, what I do, this snippet is not shown in "Goto anywhere" dialog (the one, that appears after selecting `Tools > Snippets...`. When I type `prn` in that dialogs, I see only four items brought by snippets packages installed by me:

[image]

What am I missing? Are there any special requirements for snippets to appear in "Goto anywhere" dialog? Or do I have some unnoticed bug in my snipped code?

I've read ["Snippets"](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) chapter in [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html) thoroughly, as well as ["Working With Code Snippets In Sublime Text"](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-code-snippets/) blog article in [hongkiat.com Blog](http://www.hongkiat.com/). Unfortunatelly, I found no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce **the name of the file** the Snippet its saved in. In other words, if you also want to use *prn* in the *Goto anywhere dialog*, then you must save your file with that name.